# WebDriverException: Message: '/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']' has an invalid token

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I have simple test case for testing win32 app. Through Selenium Library I trying to close app. The main point is doing it with Xpath.
It's robot's file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Process

Suite Teardown    Terminate All Processes    kill=True

*** TestCases ***
StartGui
    start_gui
    Click Element   id=btnManualRequest
    Click Element   xpath=/form[@wpfnative='True' and @title='MEV 2.7.60' and @processname='MEV.Gui']/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']

*** Keywords ***
start_gui
    Start process   C:\\test\\robot\\Winium.Desktop.Driver\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe   shell=no  alias=first
    Import Library  Selenium2Library
    ${winium_host}= Set Variable    localhost
    ${winium_port}= Set Variable    9999
    ${capabilities}=    Create Dictionary   app=C:\\test\\app\\MEV.Gui.exe  
    Create Webdriver    Remote  command_executor=http://${winium_host}:${winium_port}   desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
    sleep   8
```

I got this message:

```
WebDriverException: Message: '/form[@wpfnative='True' and @title='MEV 2.7.60' and @processname='MEV.Gui']/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']' has an invalid token.
```

Maybe I blind, but i don't understand where is mistake, and why I can't reach the element with xpath.

Update:
Just create very simple test case with calc.exe:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Process
Library Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown  Terminate All Processes    kill=True

*** TestCases ***
calcStartStop
Start process   C:\\test\\robot\\Winium.Desktop.Driver\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe   shell=no  alias=first
    ${winium_host}=    Set Variable    localhost
    ${winium_port}=    Set Variable    9999
    ${capabilities}=    Create Dictionary    app=C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe
    Create Webdriver    Remote    command_executor=http://${winium_host}:${winium_port}    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
    Click Element   xpath=//form[@processname='calc' and @class='CalcFrame' and @instance='1']/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']
```

Same answer:

```
calcStartStop                                                         | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: '//form[@processname='calc' and @class='CalcFrame
and @instance='1']/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']' has an invalid token.
```

I think the problem is that I get wrong xpath. Somebody know how to get right xpath for win32 app?

Comment: Why are you doing `Import Library  Selenium2Library` and why is it in the middle of your file not at the top?

Comment: @Goralight it's important for result?

Comment: What is `/?/?/` in your `XPath`? Do you mean `/*/*/` ?

Comment: @Andersson no, it's path what I get from Ranorex Spy tool

Comment: Not sure about robotframework, but I know in some cases I've heard selenium requires a double slash at the beginning of the xpath `//`, although I'm not clear about specific scenarios other than it obviously changing the behavior of the xpath.

Comment: @mrfreester just checked it on simple example - same answer: WebDriverException: Message: '//form[@processname='calc' and @class='CalcFrame
and @instance='1']/?/?/button[@accessiblename='Close']' has an invalid token.

Comment: @Andersson might be onto something, the similarities between those are the `?` perhaps selenium does something weird with those. I've never actually seen a `?` in an xpath before.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is not part of the XPath syntax and any `?` that is not inside a string will lead to a syntax error.

If your inspector tool returns an XPath expression that contains `?` as an axis step, you should consider using a different program. If you meant to use a wildcard for element names, use `*`, as a commenter has already pointed out.

Alternatively, are you sure the paths are not supposed to be [RanoreXPath](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/ranorexpath-tips-and-tricks/) expressions? `?` might be one of the differences between XPath and RanoreXPath.

Comment: Yep, but witch tool i can use for take Xpath of elements in win32 app?